# 'Event' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a tic-tac-toe in Python but I get this error: `'Event' object is not subscriptable`

The general idea is that when a button is pressed, if it doesn't have a text, it will change it's text in an "X" or "O" depending on the turn.
But I am stuck due to this error.

I have not much experience with Python so I need a fix easy to understand and implement. Thanks!

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
btn = [None] * 9
btn_id = [None] * 9


#position of button array
def BTNposition(): 
    i = 0
    c = 0
    k = 0
    while i < 9:
        #declaration of button array
        btn[i] = Button(window, text = "", height = 10, width = 20, borderwidth = 5, command = lambda i=i: GAME)
        btn[i].place(x= c, y= k)

        btn_id[i] = btn[i]
        print(btn[i], btn_id[i])

        i+= 1

        if c == 300:
            k += 150
            c = 0
        else:
            c += 150

                
BTNposition()

def GAME(btn): 
    turn = 0

    if btn["text"] == "" and turn % 2 == 0: #here the error
        btn.config(text = "X")
        turn += 1

    elif btn["text"] == "" and turn % 2 == 1:
        btn.config(text = "O")
        turn += 1


i = 0

#while i < 9:
    #btn[i].bind("<Button 1>", GAME)
    #find button pressed



window.bind("<Button 1>", GAME)
#print(click_position.btnp_x, click_position.btnp_y)
    
window.title('PyTris')
window.geometry("700x450")
window.mainloop()
```

I will update the post whenever I do major changes to the code.

Comment: Does the button component have an 'aux' or 'user' integer/pointer member?

Comment: `btn["text"] == "X"` should have only ONE equal, to assign the value, for now that's an equality test

Comment: in GAME you should increase `turn` only if you actually placed something - not if the tile was already used

Comment: Check what kind of thing your `GAME` is called with - probably unrelated but using `lambda inner_i = i: GAME` - without using `i` looks wrong - also better be careful with confusing reuse of scoped variables that are named identical - same f.e. with GLOBAL `btn`-list and GAME-function `btn` parameter. Your error is here: `btn["text"]` - the btn is not a button but a buttonPressEvent and that is not subscriptable

Comment: Why don't you use [pygame](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/)? It is simpler to work with when talking of Python games.

Comment: I've not used tkinter much before, but the error is probably pointing at your code: `btn["text"]` in that it isn't the type of object that can be accessed using the style you've used. I suggest using dot notation and referring to the documentation here to see what's allowed: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-handlers.html   Maybe try to see what the output of `btn.widget.get()` gives in your function

Comment: You should also use a [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) instead of a while loop - it will avoid you to initialise and increment `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

- `window.bind("<Button 1>", GAME)` a useless button that calls to `GAME` without providing a parameter hence it getting provided the default ButtonPressEvent as parameter which `GAME` is indexing into wich leads to the reported error
- no exact button placement although you calculate positions
- confused usages of `=` vs `==` inside `GAME` function
- use of global variables with danger of confusing global and local identically named ones
- variable names reused (or not used at all in case of the lambda **i**)

Fixing your code with minimalistic changes to it:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
btn = [None] * 9    
turn = 0

#position of button array
def BTNposition(): 
    c, k = 0, 0
    for i in range(9):
        # put button in array, callback is provided with the buttons index 
        # in the global array holding all the buttons
        btn[i] = Button(window, text="", height=10, width=20, borderwidth=5, 
                        command= lambda idx=i: GAME(idx))
        # fix button on coordinates
        btn[i].place(x=c, y=k)
        if c == 300:
            k += 150
            c = 0
        else:
            c += 150

# btn_nr is supposed to be an index into the global btn-array holding your buttons
def GAME(btn_nr):
    global turn # turn count is held globally, we want to modify it
    button = btn[btn_nr] # get the button we are at

    # only allow modification on buttons that are not yet X or O
    if button["text"] == "":
        # place the correct marker and advance turns
        button["text"] = "X" if turn % 2 == 0 else "O"
        turn += 1 
 
BTNposition()

window.title('PyTris')
window.geometry("700x450")
window.mainloop()
```